# Show loading indicator while SSR component renders with Next 13 App Router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

For a component like this:

```
export default async function ProjectPage({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: ProjectPageProps) {
  const study = await getStudyData(searchParams.link);

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col min-h-screen pt-16">
      <Navbar />
      <StudyPage
        className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center max-w-[680px] mx-auto pt-16"
        studyData={study.studyData}
        section={params.section}
        page={params.page}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

As the page loads, there is some latency because of the `await getStudyData`, and a white page is briefly displayed. The client would like a loading indicator displaying until the page is fully displayed.

How is this possible with SSR?

Comment: yes it is quiet simple answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77234488/19983148